# Probability problem: A company takes out an insurance policy to cover accidents that occur at its manufacturing plant.

Tags: probability

A company takes out an insurance policy to cover accidents that occur at its manufacturing plant.

The probability that one or more accidents will occur during any given month is 0.6.

The number of accidents that occur in any given month is independent of the number of accidents that occur in all other months.

Calculate the probability that there will be at least four months in which no accidents occur before the fourth month in which at least one accident occurs.

Comment: before the fourth month? but u wanted atleast 4 months before it...

Comment: It is a war of words... Thank you for your help!

Comment: what's correct then?

Comment: The text of the problem is correct. I double checked.

Comment: This is not at all clear.  How long a time period are we observing for?   And then there's the (previously mentioned) confusion over the four months.  Assume you take on the policy on Jan1.  Please give, explicitly, some scenarios that meet your conditions and some that do not.

Comment: What I wrote is what is given. Test takers are supposed to solve the problem in five minutes. I am glad that geniuses like you are also struggling with the problem because it make feel less concerned about my problem-solving skills. I will publish my answer, if nobody publish an answer.

Comment: As stated, there is simply no way to address the question.  It doesn't make any sense.  If you want a wild guess, the question is meant to cover one year and it is asking for the probability that in that one year there will be a sequence of at least four consecutive accident free months.  But, really, this is just a guess.  I made the "one year" bit up entirely and I just chose an interpretation of the "four months".

Comment: I don't understand your answer.  What problem are you solving?  How many months are you considering?  If you are thinking about infinitely many months (and it looks as if you might be) then the answer is clearly $1$.

Comment: Hold on:  Maybe the problem makes sense after all, maybe I was misreading it.  Now I think it means "keep a running total of the accident free months and the months with accidents.  What is the probability that the accident free months get to $4$ first?"

Comment: I am assuming infinite months that sum 1, but as the problem says "at least four months in which no accidents occur." I think that the elements with 3,2, 1 and 0 months with no accidents should be subtracted from 1. Right?

Comment: I posted the calculation using the interpretation I just gave, which I now believe to be correct.  It matches your answer so I expect you are using the same interpretation.  Apologies for the confusion I caused by misreading the problem initially.

Comment: @lulu I appreciate your opinions. No apologies are necessary. However, thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r = 4$ be the number of months with failures and $p = 0.6$. Now let $X$ be the r.v. that there are $k$ months without accidents before there are $r$ months with accidents. We have $X$ ~ $NegBin(4, 0.6)$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution

Thus we can compute the probability of $P(X \geq 4) = 1-P(X < 4)$

The actual calculation can be left as an execise.

Answer (score 1):

The language that the author used to make the question is hard to understand, and I would like to know if it was on purpose to increase the difficulty of the problem. However, after thinking 24 hours of the problem, I feel awful because we are supposed to solve the problem in 5 minutes.

Anyway, here is my solution:

I will call A the probability that there is at least one accident in a particular month, A = 0.6. I will call N the probability that we have no accidents in a particular month, N = 1 - 0.6 = 0.4

We need to sum infinite elements like any combination of (4 N's and 4 A's), (5 N's and 4 A's), (6 N's and 4 A's), (7 N's and 4 A's), and we need to go to the infinite (N's and 4 A's). (Something important is that the last factor is always an A)

We know that the sum of any infinite series is 1, when involves probability. Thus instead of summing infinite elements we can sum the complement that is finite, and subtract than from 1.

The complement has the following elements:

(3A, 0N, A); in any order, however we always have an A at the end, plus (3A, 1N, A); (3A, 2N, A); (3A, 3N, A).

All that is: C(3,0) 0.4^0 0.6^4 + C(4,1) 0.4^1 0.6^4 + 
C(5,2) 0.4^2 0.6^4 + C(6,3) 0.4^3 0.6^4 = 0.71

For that reason, the answer is 1 - 0.71 = 0.29

As Hongyu Wan brilliantly mentioned the finite elements present a negative binomial that is just a binomial for the first n-1 elements, times the the probability of the nth element.

Comment: @Idea Can you check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I was misreading the problem originally.  Assume the problem means "keep a running total of the months with no accident and the months with an accident.  What's the probability that the accident-free months get to $4$ first?"

Thus, it is analogous to a "best of  $7$" game series where our favorite team wins a random game with probability $.4$  Here, we want the probability that our preferred team wins the series.

To solve that problem, assume that all $7$ games are played.  We want our team team to win at least $4$ games out of the $7$ thus the answer is $$\sum_{i=4}^7\binom 7i\times .4^i\times .6^{7-i}=0.289792$$

Which confirms the answer from the OP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your teachings! I love your different approach...

Comment: No problem at all.